# output of a recursion implementation

Tags: python, recursion

I've try to implement a recursion algorithm: 'X' is a global variable

```
def build_paths(m,n):
    Result = []
    Move = X[(m,n)][1]
    if Move[0] == "None":
       return(Move[0])
    else:
       if Move[0]=="UP":
          m -= 1
       elif Move[0]=="Left":
          n -= 1
       else:
          m -= 1
          n -= 1
       Result = [build_paths(m,n),Move[0]]
    return(Result)
```

This generates

```
[[[[[[['None', 'LEFT'], 'DIAG'], 'DIAG'], 'DIAG'], 'UP'], 'DIAG'], 'DIAG']
```

This is in essence what I want, but I really want is

```
['None','LEFT','DIAG','DIAG','UP','DIAG','DIAG']
```

Then I changed the 2nd last line of my recursion function to

```
Result = [build_paths(m,n)].extend(Move[0])
```

I think logically it is correct, i.e., I keep on extend my list, but eventually, it only outputs

```
None
```

I couldn't figure out why it happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`build_paths()` returns a list, and `extend` returns None (it modifies its argument), so you'd want:

```
Result = build_paths(m,n)
Result.append(Move[0])
```